# Clarification on interpolation techniques in Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I want to experiment with different interpolation techniques. Some determining factors for choosing the appropriate interpolation techniques are:

1. Density of data (Checking if the data is dense or sparse)
2. Dimensionality of data (High dimensional or low dimensional)
3. Size of the data (for lower computation time)

As:

- *Radial Basis* is good for sparse & high dimensional data
- *Cubic Spline* is good for dense data
- *Polynomial Interpolation* is better for small and low dimensional datasets as it can fit
  accurate lines/curves for functions upto 3 degrees.

My doubts are:

1. Is there a sure shot way of checking the density of the interpolation column's data distribution?
   Some techniques I have identified are:

- If the number of missing/empty values is significant (>=50%) the data is sparse.
- If the range of majority of the data values is small & the standard deviation is small,
  then the data is considered dense, else, sparse.
- Visualization using a scatter plot.

2. Is the following concept regarding high & low dimensionality right?

   If the number of dimensions/variables is the same as or outnumbers the number of rows,
   then the data is high dimensional, else, low-dimensional.
3. Can I include a rule in my code that if my data is low dimensional & the number of rows is less than **100,000** then it's a small dataset, else, large?

I gathered the above points after a lot of research. Do let me know if my above points right.

**Note:** I understand that some of the above points like size of the dataset & differentiating between sparse & dense data distribution are subjective, but I want to know if they are accurate to a decent extent.

Comment: For the readers: [pandas.DataFrame.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html). 1. I haven't found a function to compute a column's density in pandas. Pandas is just here to hold your data in a nice-to-work-with format; although it has many features. You should look into a statistical library for that. 2. In high-dimensional data, the number of variables/features is large compared to the number of observations, but it is not strictly defined by having more variables/features than observations. 3. Yes you can.

Comment: 2.[Introduction to high-dimensional data](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/high-dimensional-stats-r/01-introduction-to-high-dimensional-data/index.html). 3. Compute a high-dimensionality boolean, then create the condition: `is_large = is_high_density & (len(df)>100_000`)